# Internet connection inside Docker container in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes pod based on a Jenkins/slave container to which I mount a Docker socket and a Docker binary file with necessary kernel modules in privileged mode.

Inside that pod I build a Docker image, in which I run Docker container. Inside that container I don't have Internet connection at all because the pod container uses a flannel network `(198.x.x.x)` and that container uses bridged docker network `(172.x.x.x)`, which is not available inside the pod container.

How can I make the Internet available inside the second container which is being created inside the Kubernetes pod container?

Using Docker API in Jenkins pipeline is not a solution for me as long as it limits output of error logs and I can not commit changes made in the second container because of immediate removing of that container after build.

Comment: I have a similar problem, I don’t have access to the external network from the Pod. How did you resolve iptables conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion k8s should not be used to build docker images as it is an orchestration platform, but there is an [open issue in the GitHub k8s repository](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/1806). In conclusion, building docker images on a k8s cluster seems not to be possible at the moment.

Comment: I was able to resolve it long ago. There was an issue with iptables rules because of conflicts with flannel interface. As a result rules for docker0 bridge interface were not applied correctly after each server reboot. Now everything is being worked properly. Thank you!